# Export schema including materialized view definition, but excluding the rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to do an Oracle Data Pump Export (expdp).

I want to export the definition and data for most of the schema, but exclude the rows for some of the larger tables. I have used exclude table_data option to successfully exclude the rows for some of the tables, but I have one materialized view that I want to also exclude (the rows, not the definition). I have been unable to find the right exclude parameters to achieve this.

Is it possible to exclude the data for an individual materialized view while including the definition for that materialized view and data for other exported items?

My exclude parameter is:

```
exclude=table_data:"like 'MV!_%' ESCAPE '!'"
```

yet in the log I still see:

```
. . exported "HERMES_DEMO"."MV_MESSAGE_SUMMARIES_UNION":"S10"  8.569 MB   43521 rows
```

Comment: Can you show us the expdp command you used?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 I've added some further details, the command is built up dynamically, so it's not really possible to show it.